# When a monoidal closed category is cartesian closed

Tags: ct.category-theory, symmetric-monoidal-categories, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $C$ be a monoidal closed category with tensor $\otimes$ and internal hom $[-, -]$.

Suppose that

1. $C$ acts by adjoint monads, i.e. $- \otimes X$ is a comonad and $[X, -]$ is a monad, and each $F : X \rightarrow Y$ in $C$ gives a natural transformation which respects these structures.
2. $- \otimes 1$ and $[1, -]$ are naturally isomorphic to the identity functors on $C$.
3. $\otimes$ is symmetric (tensor has a twist map and twisting twice is the identity); equivalently $[-,D] : C \rightarrow C$ is adjoint to itself.
   $$ \text{Hom}(A \otimes B, D) \cong \text{Hom}(B \otimes A, D) $$
   or
   $$\text{Hom}(A, [B, D]) \cong \text{Hom}(B, [A, D])$$
   (they're equivalent)

> **Q: What more is required to demonstrate that $\otimes$ is categorical product so that $C$ is cartesian closed?** Are the current conditions sufficient (I think not)?

Some thoughts:

1. gives a projection map $\pi: A \otimes B \rightarrow A$ for each $A$ and $B$. 2. Gives a twist map $\tau : A \otimes B \rightarrow B \otimes A$. We get projections $\pi$ and $\pi \circ \tau$.

Let $\alpha : X \rightarrow A$ and $\beta : X \rightarrow B$ be two maps in $C$. I want  there to be a unique map $f : A \otimes B$ such that $\pi \circ \tau \circ f = \beta$ and $\pi \circ f = \alpha$.

Consider the map $(\alpha \otimes \beta) \circ \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal map apparent from 1. and 2.

I need:

1. $\pi \circ (\alpha \otimes \beta) \circ \Delta = \alpha$.
2. $\pi \circ \tau \circ (\alpha \otimes \beta) \circ \Delta = \beta$.
3. If $\pi \circ \tau \circ f = \alpha$ and $\pi \circ f = \beta$, then $f =  (\alpha \otimes \beta) \circ \Delta$

Comment: Doesn't the second statement in (3) follow already from $C$ being braided?

Comment: This is somewhat a rephrasing of Fox's theorem. See the discussion around Thm 2.22 in my paper Functorial Semantics for partial theories.

Comment: @TimCampion I'm not sure but do assume it is braided symmetric monoidal.

Comment: @TimCampion also more people should know that you can view the tensor symmetry as conjugate to the hom-hom adjunction- commutativity arising from adjunctions!

Comment: @TimChampion oh, I see what you're saying. I made some edits.